# Removing fixed height makes the slider collapse intially when it loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a very simple responsive slider with vanilla JavaScript. It works great but has one issue which I am not able to figure it out. I am hoping someone from this community can help me.

Below is the slider demo I have in CodePen

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/praveenc78/pen/dygGyKV)

What I am trying to do is to remove the fixed height I have on .pc-mslider container, if I remove the fixed height the slider is collapsed when is it loaded due to the fact the height is not set. If I set the height and resize the window, it looks whacked either with huge space at the bottom or the content is hidden.

I am looking a way to fix this.

Thanks

I tried removing the height and calculating the height based on first slide using the code below

```
// Set the initial height based on the first slide
const slider = document.querySelector('.pc-mslider');
const firstSlideHeight = slides[0].offsetHeight;
slider.style.height = `${firstSlideHeight}px`;
```

But this is not working as it adds inline style height:0px .pc-mslider

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this `slider.style.height = '${firstSlideHeight}px';` entirely, and then stop using `position: absolute` on your `.pc-mslider-wrapper`.  If it were me, I would actually go through and remove all uses of both `position: absolute` and `position: relative` from your stylesheet; I don't really want to track down the exact interaction that is causing all of your issues, but you are using the `position` property pretty liberally and it does tend to introduce these kinds of issues if you aren't careful.  In your case, since you're using `transform` to move your stuff around, I don't really see any reason to use `position` at all, so I would just...not.